# While creating two very similar images one is corrupted with artifacts

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage

In short, the algorithm takes three images: source1, source2, hidden. Then it hides the hidden image within source1 and source2 (producing output1 and output2). If you place output1 on output2 the hidden image can be seen. However output2 is getting corrupted somehow and while the general idea works, the hidden image (and source1) can be seen in it. (it's hard, but possible)

I'm trying to implement the algorithm from http://datagenetics.com/blog/november32013/index.html. (Scroll down to "How does this magic work?" to skip the introduction).

EDIT: Turns out that setTwo method somehow gains identical blanks. Enforcing and rerandomizing blank2 fixes the problem. However, I still have no idea how do identical data get in there... After all, before calling the setTwo algorithm I always randomize two different numbers.. Anyone sees the reason for it?

EDIT2: Added checks before every call to setTwo to test if the arguments are equal. The check failed everytime, while the check within setTwo catches the problem. I have no idea how the data corrupts.

[1st image - source1, source2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfhOP.png)

[2nd image - hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyDUQ.png)

[3rd image - output 1 - correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wIQk.png)

[4th image - output 2 - problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZghYE.png)

```
package visualcryptography;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author Ugnius
 */
public class VisualCryptography {

    BufferedImage sourceOne;
    BufferedImage sourceTwo;
    BufferedImage hiddenImage;
    BufferedImage outputOne;
    BufferedImage outputTwo;
    GUI loadingBar;

    static final int black = java.awt.Color.BLACK.getRGB();
    static final int white = java.awt.Color.WHITE.getRGB();
    static final int whiteToWrite = (new Color(255, 255, 255, 0)).getRGB();
    Random r = new Random();
    //Color cl;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public VisualCryptography(BufferedImage source1, BufferedImage source2, BufferedImage hidden, GUI loadingBar) throws Exception {
        if ((source1.getHeight() != source2.getHeight()) || (source2.getHeight() != hidden.getHeight())) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        if ((source1.getWidth() != source2.getWidth()) || (source2.getWidth() != hidden.getWidth())) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        sourceOne = source1;
        sourceTwo = source2;
        hiddenImage = hidden;
        this.loadingBar = loadingBar;
        //cl = java.awt.Color.WHITE;
        //cl = new Color(cl.getRed(), cl.getGreen(), cl.getBlue(), 0);
        //white = cl.getRGB();
        //System.out.println("this is WHITE:" + cl.getRGB());
        //System.out.println("this is my white:" + (new Color(0,0,0).getRGB()));
        //white = 1;
        //cl = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
        //white = cl.getRGB();

        //white = -1;
        //white = 16777215;
        //white = java.awt.Color.WHITE.getRGB();
        //byte alpha = (byte) 0xff;
        //int mc = (alpha << 24) | 0x00ffffff;
        //white = white & mc;
        //System.out.println("this is my transparent white:" + white);
        //System.out.println("this is black" + black);
    }

    public void process() throws IOException {
        int total = sourceOne.getHeight();
        outputOne = new BufferedImage(sourceOne.getWidth() * 2, sourceOne.getHeight() * 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        outputTwo = new BufferedImage(sourceTwo.getWidth() * 2, sourceTwo.getHeight() * 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int height = 0; height < sourceOne.getHeight(); height++) {
            System.out.println(height + " / " + total);

            //loadingBar.repaint();
            for (int width = 0; width < sourceOne.getWidth(); width++) {
                //Random r = new Random();
                //if ((height > 87) && (width > 190)){

                //System.out.println("Hello");
                //}
                if (hiddenImage.getRGB(width, height) != white) {
                    //when the hidden image pixel is BLACK
                    //the combined two cypgher images (OR) have to have all four subpixels set.
                    if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) != white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) != white)) {
                        //when bouth source images also have a black pixel, this is easy. Both cypher images need to have three out of
                        //the four subpixels set. The only constraint is that the missing subpixel is not the same on both layers.
                        //one pixel is randomly selected on the first layer, and one is randomly select from the other three on the
                        //second layer
                        int randomized = r.nextInt(4);
                        //randomized = 0; top left
                        //randomized = 1; top right
                        //randomized = 2; bottom left
                        //randomized = 3; bottom right
                        this.setThree(width, height, randomized, outputOne);
                        int newRandomized = r.nextInt(4);
                        while (randomized == newRandomized) {
                            newRandomized = r.nextInt(4);
                        }
                        this.setThree(width, height, newRandomized, outputTwo);
                    } else {
                        if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) != white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) == white)) {
                            //When the first image has a black pixel (requiring three subpixels set), and the second image 
                            //has a white pixel (requiring two subpixels set), as above, first, a random single subpixel is
                            //selected on the black layer to remove. Next two subpixels are randomly selected on the second 
                            //layer with the constraint that one of the selected subpixels is the same as the gap in the 
                            //first layer. In this way, when the two are combined, four black subpixels are displayed.
                            int randomized = r.nextInt(4);
                            //randomized = 0; top left
                            //randomized = 1; top right
                            //randomized = 2; bottom left
                            //randomized = 3; bottom right
                            this.setThree(width, height, randomized, outputOne);
                            int random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                            while (random1 == randomized) {
                                random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                            }
                            int random2 = r.nextInt(4);
                            while ((random2 == randomized) || random1 == random2) {
                                random2 = r.nextInt(4);
                            }
                            this.setTwo(width, height, random1, random2, outputTwo);
                        } else {
                            if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) == white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) != white)) {
                                //the opposite happens when the first layer is white, and the second layer is black
                                int randomized = r.nextInt(4);
                                //randomized = 0; top left
                                //randomized = 1; top right
                                //randomized = 2; bottom left
                                //randomized = 3; bottom right
                                this.setThree(width, height, randomized, outputTwo);
                                int random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                while (random1 == randomized) {
                                    random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                }
                                int random2 = r.nextInt(4);
                                while ((random2 == randomized) || random1 == random2) {
                                    random2 = r.nextInt(4);
                                }
                                this.setTwo(width, height, random1, random2, outputOne);
                            } else {
                                if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) == white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) == white)) {
                                    int randomized = r.nextInt(4);
                                    int randomized1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                    while (randomized == randomized1) {
                                        randomized1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                    }
                                    this.setTwo(width, height, randomized, randomized1, outputOne);
                                    int[] remaining = new int[2];
                                    int counter = 0;
                                    int number = 0;
                                    while (counter != 2) {
                                        if ((number != randomized) && (number != randomized1)) {
                                            remaining[counter] = number;
                                            counter++;
                                        }
                                        number++;
                                    }
                                    this.setTwo(width, height, remaining[0], remaining[1], outputTwo);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //when the hidden image pixel is WHITE
                    //the combined two cypher images (OR) have to have any three subpixels set
                    if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) != white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) != white)) {
                        //When both source images have a black pixel, this is easy. Both cypher images need to have 
                        //three out of the four subpixels set, and these need to be the same subpixels. Three subpixels
                        //are randomly selected and these are set on both of the cypher image layers.
                        int random = r.nextInt(4);
                        this.setThree(width, height, random, outputOne);
                        this.setThree(width, height, random, outputTwo);
                    } else {
                        if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) != white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) == white)) {
                            //When the first image has a black pixel (requiring three subpixels set), and the second image 
                            //has a white pixel (requiring two subpixels set), as above, first, three random subpixels
                            //are selected on the first layer. Next one of these three subpixels is randomly selected for 
                            //removal and this pattern is used on the second layer.
                            int random = r.nextInt(4);
                            this.setThree(width, height, random, outputOne);
                            int random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                            while (random == random1) {
                                random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                            }
                            this.setTwo(width, height, random, random1, outputTwo);
                        } else {
                            if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) == white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) != white)) {
                                int random = r.nextInt(4);
                                this.setThree(width, height, random, outputTwo);
                                int random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                while (random == random1) {
                                    random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                }
                                this.setTwo(width, height, random, random1, outputOne);
                            } else {
                                if ((sourceOne.getRGB(width, height) == white) && (sourceTwo.getRGB(width, height) == white)) {
                                    //Finally, if both source pixels are white (requiring two subpixels set), two are selected
                                    //at random on the first layer, then one of these is duplicated on the second layer, and a 
                                    //second random subpixel is selected on the second layer (from the two white subpixels not 
                                    //selected on the first layer). Both layers have two subpixels, and when combined, there are
                                    //three subpixels visbile.
                                    int random = r.nextInt(4);
                                    //this.setThree(width, height, random, outputTwo);
                                    int random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                    while (random == random1) {
                                        random1 = r.nextInt(4);
                                    }
                                    this.setTwo(width, height, random, random1, outputOne);
                                    int random2 = r.nextInt(4);
                                    if (random2 == random) {
                                        random2 = r.nextInt(4);
                                    }
                                    this.setTwo(width, height, random, random2, outputTwo);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void setThree(int x, int y, int blank, BufferedImage im) {
        //blank = 0; top left
        //blank = 1; top right
        //blank = 2; bottom left
        //blank = 3; bottom right

        im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y, black);
        im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y, black);
        im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y + 1, black);
        im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1, black);
        switch (blank) {
            case 0:
                im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 1:
                im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 2:
                im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y + 1, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 3:
                im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1, whiteToWrite);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setTwo(int x, int y, int blank1, int blank2, BufferedImage im) {
        //blank = 0; top left
        //blank = 1; top right
        //blank = 2; bottom left
        //blank = 3; bottom right
        im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y, black);
        im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y, black);
        im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y + 1, black);
        im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1, black);
        switch (blank1) {
            case 0:
                im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 1:
                im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 2:
                im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y + 1, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 3:
                im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1, whiteToWrite);
                break;
        }
        switch (blank2) {
            case 0:
                im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 1:
                im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 2:
                im.setRGB(2 * x, 2 * y + 1, whiteToWrite);
                break;
            case 3:
                im.setRGB(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1, whiteToWrite);
                break;
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage[] getOutput() {
        BufferedImage[] output = new BufferedImage[2];
        output[0] = outputOne;
        output[1] = outputTwo;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for not giving "the answer". But I'm pretty sure that hardly *anybody* is willing or able to debug a piece of code that involves

```
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...eight levels of nesting and 28 occurrences of `nextInt`.

Whatever you are doing there: I think this is easier. **Much** easier. By closely looking at the pattern of the 2x2 pixels, you can identify very simple rules: The initial pattern is

```
WB
BW
```

The "coin toss" determines whether the pixels are flipped horizontally, to yield

```
BW
WB
```

In the second image, these patterns are just flipped vertically, if (and only if) the input pixel was black.

Here is an example implementation, maybe you'll find it helpful.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class VisualCryptographyTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        BufferedImage image = createImage("Password");

        JLabel originalImageLabel = 
            new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        f.getContentPane().add(originalImageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        BufferedImage cypherImage0 = createCypherImage(image, true);
        BufferedImage cypherImage1 = createCypherImage(image, false);
        VisualCryptographyPanel visualCryptographyPanel = 
            new VisualCryptographyPanel(cypherImage0, cypherImage1);
        f.getContentPane().add(visualCryptographyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static BufferedImage createCypherImage(BufferedImage image, boolean first)
    {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        BufferedImage cypherImage = new BufferedImage(
            w+w,h+h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        final int BLACK = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
        final int WHITE = 0;

        for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
            {
                int cx = x+x;
                int cy = y+y;
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);

                int p00 = WHITE;
                int p10 = BLACK;
                int p01 = BLACK;
                int p11 = WHITE;
                int temp = 0;
                boolean flipH = random.nextBoolean();
                if (flipH)
                {
                    temp=p00; p00=p10; p10=temp;
                    temp=p01; p01=p11; p11=temp;
                }
                if (first && rgb == Color.BLACK.getRGB())
                {
                    temp=p00; p00=p01; p01=temp;
                    temp=p10; p10=p11; p11=temp;
                }
                cypherImage.setRGB(cx+0, cy+0, p00);
                cypherImage.setRGB(cx+1, cy+0, p10);
                cypherImage.setRGB(cx+0, cy+1, p01);
                cypherImage.setRGB(cx+1, cy+1, p11);

            }
        }
        return cypherImage;
    }



    private static BufferedImage createImage(String message)
    {
        float fontSize = 50.0f;
        int w = 300;
        int h = 100;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(fontSize));
        g.drawString(message, 30, 75);
        g.dispose();
        return image;

    }
}


class VisualCryptographyPanel extends JPanel 
    implements MouseMotionListener, KeyListener
{
    private final BufferedImage cypherImage0;
    private final BufferedImage cypherImage1;
    private int imageX = 0;
    private int imageY = 0;

    VisualCryptographyPanel(
        BufferedImage cypherImage0,
        BufferedImage cypherImage1)
    {
        setFocusable(true);
        this.cypherImage0 = cypherImage0;
        this.cypherImage1 = cypherImage1;
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        int x = (getWidth() - cypherImage0.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - cypherImage0.getHeight()) / 2;
        g.drawImage(cypherImage0, x, y, null);

        g.drawImage(cypherImage1, imageX, imageY, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        imageX = e.getX();
        imageY = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            imageY--;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            imageY++;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            imageX--;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            imageX++;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }


}
```